# Trying to make a function that prints an array range. I'm given the start, stop and step values. I keep getting an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, arguments, range

I am trying to write a function that returns a list of integers from a 'start' value (inclusive) to a 'stop' value (exclusive) and am given the 'step' (or number to increment by...).

The function is supposed to be able to handle different amount of arguments passed in. I believe I have the function most of the way completed but I seem to be getting an infinite loop and am unsure why or how to proceed.

Here is the code I have written so far...

```
function range(start, stop, step) {
    if (arguments.length===1) {
        start = 0;
        stop = arguments[0];
        step = 1;
    } else if (arguments.length===2) {
        start = arguments[0];
        stop = arguments[1];
        step = 1;
    } else if (arguments.length===3) {
        start = arguments[0];
        stop = arguments[1];
        step = arguments[2];
    }
    // define result array
    let result = [];
    // create a for-loop
    for (start; start < stop; start + step) {
        result.push(start);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And here are some example calls and their expected outputs...

```
range(10); -> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
range(1,11); -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
range(0,30,5); -> [0,5,10,15,20,25]
range(0,-10,-1); -> [0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9]
```

The function is also supposed to be able to do negative ranges with negative 'step' values as well.

Could someone explain to me why I seem to be getting an infinite loop?

Comment: `start + step` -> `start += step`

Comment: A `for` loop is made up of three expressions and a body: The expressions are (in order) *initialization*, *test*, and *update*. The *update* step should update something that is being used by the *test* step to determine whether the loop should keep going. `start + step` doesn't *update* anything, it just does a calculation and throws away the result. As @VLAZ said, you want to *update* `start`: `start += step`.

Comment: Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't change start value in your `for` loop. you have missed an `=`.

```
for (start; start < stop; start += step)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look through and explain! I obviously need sleed!

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains several mistake. For example you reassign values to the arguments, which one should never do. Then your *for* loop only works for stops which are greater than starts. And there is no error checking at all. Here is a self-explaining version which should work:

```js
function range(start, stop, step) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (!Number.isInteger(arguments[i])) {
      return [ 'Invalid arguments: all arguments must be of type Integer' ]
    }
  }
  let from = 0
  let to = 0
  let increment = 1
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    to = arguments[0]
  } else if (arguments.length === 2) {
    [ from, to ] = arguments
  } else if (arguments.length === 3) {
    [ from, to, increment ] = arguments
  } else {
    return [ 'Invalid arguments: 0 or more than 3 arguments' ]
  }
  if (increment > 0 && from > to) {
    return [ 'Invalid arguments: step must be negative' ]
  } else if (increment < 0 && from < to) {
    return [ 'Invalid arguments: step must be positive' ]
  } else if (increment === 0) {
    return [ 'Invalid arguments: step cannot be 0' ]
  }
  let result = []
  if (increment > 0) {
    for (from; from < to; from += increment) {
      result.push(from)
    }
  } else {
    for (from; from > to; from += increment) {
      result.push(from)
    }
  }
  return result
}

console.log(range(10))             // [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
console.log(range(1, 11))          // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
console.log(range(0, 30, 5))       // [0,5,10,15,20,25]
console.log(range(0, -10, -1))     // [0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9]
console.log(range('0', 'abc'))     // Invalid arguments: all arguments must be of type Integer
console.log(range())               // Invalid arguments: 0 or more than 3 arguments
console.log(range(0, -10, 1))      // Invalid arguments: step must be negative
console.log(range(-20, -10, -1))   // Invalid arguments: step must be positive
console.log(range(0, 10, 0))       // Invalid arguments: step cannot be 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another range solution:

```
const range = (start, stop, step) => {
  // manipulation with arguments
  const itemsCout = Math.ceil((stop - start) / step)
  return [...Array(itemsCout)].map((_value, index) => index*step+start )
};

console.log(range(1,10,2)); // [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ]
console.log(range(0,30,5)); // [ 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ]
console.log(range(0,-10,-1)); // [ 0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9 ]
```